# Prove that $f$ is a convex function

Tags: convex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be such that for all $x,y \in\mathbb R,\ \ f(y) \geq f (x) + f'(x)(y−x).$

How to prove that $f$ is a convex function?

Comment: Hint: By hypotesis $$f(y)\geqslant f(x)+f'(x)(x-y),\qquad f(x)\geqslant f(y)+f'(y)(y-x)$$use this to prove that $f'(x)-f'(y)\geqslant 0$. Take then $z=\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y$ (with $\lambda\in(0,1)$) and apply the hypotesis, again to get $$f(z)\geqslant f(x)+f'(x)(z-x),\qquad f(z)\geqslant f(y)+f'(y)(z-y)$$ once here, multiply the first of the last two inequalities by $\lambda$ and the second by $1-\lambda$ and sum the two, then you get the conclusion (with a bit of manipulating)

Comment: Thanks @Alessandro! Can you please elaborate a bit what do you mean by "and  sum the two, then you get the conclusion (with a bit of manipulating)"

Comment: Well, if you have two inequalities $a\geqslant b$ and $c\geqslant d$, you can sum them in $a+c\geqslant b+d$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $z = \alpha x + (1-\alpha) y$ where $0 \le  \alpha \le  1 $.
By hyopthesis we have:
\begin{align}
&f(x)  \ge f'(z)(x-z) + f(z)  = f'(z)\bigg[x - \alpha x + (1-\alpha) y\bigg] + f(z) =   (1-\alpha)f'(z)(x- y) + f(z)\\
\implies & \alpha f(x) \ge \alpha(1-\alpha)f'(z)(x- y) + \alpha f(z)\qquad\text{(1)}.
\end{align}
Again by hypothesis:
\begin{align}
&f(y)  \ge f'(z)(y-z) + f(z)  = f'(z)\bigg[y - \alpha x + (1-\alpha) y\bigg] + f(z) =   -\alpha f'(z)(x- y) + f(z)\\
\implies & (1-\alpha)f(y) =   -\alpha(1-\alpha) f'(z)(x- y) + (1-\alpha)f(z)\qquad\text{(2)}.
\end{align}
Adding (1) and (2):
\begin{align}
\alpha f(x) + (1-\alpha)f(y) \ge \alpha f(z) + (1-\alpha) f(z)  = f(z) =  f(\alpha x + (1-\alpha)y).
\end{align}